# Product filtering using multiple HTML5 data-attributtes

Tags: jquery, sorting, filtering, product, custom-data-attribute

I have a function that I would like to return products based on a usermade filter via check boxes.

Basically:

> Each product has multiple data-attributtes, for example: data-brand="acer", data-price="2995", data-screensize="15.6", data-processor="intel"

So say i'm lining up 40 products, the users need to be able to narrow down the product listing.

At the moment my function, shows all that is clicked, and doesnt narrow down the product listing.

Not being a JQuery shark, I could use som input on how I can filter the products.

---

I have added a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Klemme/czE6x/14/

Any feedback appreciated lots, thank you.

---

This is what I have at the moment:

```
function filterFunction()
{
    //if( $( "input[name='screen_group[]']:checked" ).length > 0 ) 
    if( $( "input[type='checkbox']:checked" ).length > 0 ) 
    {
        $( '.produkt_gruppe_div' ).hide();

        searchScreens   = $( "input[name='screen_group[]']:checked" ).map( function() { return $( this ).val(); }).get(); // <----  
        searchBrands    = $( "input[name='brand_group[]']:checked" ).map( function() { return $( this ).val(); }).get(); // <----   
        // Combine marked filters (checkboxes)
        var params      = searchScreens.concat( searchBrands );

        // Available data-atr, from the first product element
        filterAttributtes = $( '.product_gruppe_div:first' ).data();

        var searchValues = [];
        // Loop marked checkboxes,display products that has a matching data-atr="value"
        $.each( params, function( key, value )
        {           
            $('[data-screensize="' + value + '"]').show();
            $('[data-brand_name="' + value + '"]').show();          

            //$( '.produkt_gruppe_div' ).filter('[data-screensize="' + value + '"]').addClass('screen').fadeIn(300);    

            //$( '.produkt_gruppe_div' ).filter('[data-brand_name="' + value + '"]').addClass('brand').fadeIn(300);         
        }); 
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Vis alle, hvis der ikke er afmærket noget
        $('.produkt_gruppe_div').show();
    }   
}
```

So when a user selects "Acer and Lenovo" as Brand, and "15.6 and 14" as screensize, I need to only display the products which data-brand="acer of lenove" and data-screensize="15.6 or 14" and so on.

There is at the moment 6 filteres to each products, which defines the product details. And I have tjeckboxes that has an ID corresponding to the data-atr="value".

Hope someone can see how I can hide all, and then only show products that contains either of the values.

Best regards, Klemme

EDIT EDIT:::

**Here is my markup:**

```
<div class="product_gruppe_div" data-brand="acer" data-screensize="15.6" data-processor="intel"> - Product info - </div>

<div class="product_gruppe_div" data-brand="lenovo" data-screensize="15.6" data-processor="intel"> - Product info - </div>

<div class="product_gruppe_div" data-brand="acer" data-screensize="15.6" data-processor="intel"> - Product info - </div>

<div class="product_gruppe_div" data-brand="hp" data-screensize="15.4" data-processor="intel"> - Product info - </div>

<div class="product_gruppe_div" data-brand="hp" data-screensize="14" data-processor="intel"> - Product info - </div>

<div class="product_gruppe_div" data-brand="fujitsu" data-screensize="14" data-processor="intel"> - Product info - </div>
```

And checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="screen_group[]" value="18.4" id="18.4" onClick="filterFunction()" />&nbsp;<span class="filter_paragraphs">18,4"</span><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="screen_group[]" value="17.3" id="17.3" onClick="filterFunction()" />&nbsp;<span class="filter_paragraphs">17,3"</span><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="screen_group[]" value="15.6" id="15.6" onClick="filterFunction()" />&nbsp;<span class="filter_paragraphs">15,6"</span><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="screen_group[]" value="15.5" id="15.5" onClick="filterFunction()" />&nbsp;<span class="filter_paragraphs">15,5"</span><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="screen_group[]" value="15.4" id="15.4" onClick="filterFunction()" />&nbsp;<span class="filter_paragraphs">15,4"</span><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="screen_group[]" value="14" id="14" onClick="filterFunction()" />&nbsp;<span class="filter_paragraphs">14"</span><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="screen_group[]" value="13.3" id="13.3" onClick="filterFunction()" />&nbsp;<span class="filter_paragraphs">13,3"</span><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="screen_group[]" value="12.5" id="12.5" onClick="filterFunction()" />&nbsp;<span class="filter_paragraphs">12,5"</span><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="screen_group[]" value="11.6" id="11.6" onClick="filterFunction()" />&nbsp;<span class="filter_paragraphs">11,6"</span><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="screen_group[]" value="11" id="11" onClick="filterFunction()" />&nbsp;<span class="filter_paragraphs">11"</span><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="screen_group[]" value="10.1" id="10.1" onClick="filterFunction()" />&nbsp;<span class="filter_paragraphs">10,1"</span><br />
```

The same principle for brand, and processor and so on.

EDIT TWO:

Here is another option, where I can list multiple brands, and after that tjeck what is visible on the screen, and then run a tjeck on screensizes.

This lets me filter on all brands, and a screensize on say 15.6".

Problem is, that I can only choose ONE screensize checkbox, if I choose multiple, I loose all the products on the screen.

Cant seem to see hos I can modify it.

PATEL:

Do you reckon it can be integrated in your code on: http://jsfiddle.net/Klemme/czE6x/38/ ?

```
function filterFunction()
{
if( $( "input[type='checkbox']:checked" ).length > 0 ) 
{
$( '.produkt_gruppe_div' ).hide();

searchScreens   = $( "input[name='screen_group[]']:checked" ).map( function() { return $( this ).val(); }).get(); // <----  
    searchBrands    = $( "input[name='brand_group[]']:checked" ).map( function() { return $( this ).val(); }).get(); // <----   

var searchValues = [];

$.each( searchBrands, function( key, value )
{   
    console.log( searchBrands );    

    // Vis kun de valgte brands på siden
    $('[data-brand_name="' + value + '"]').show();
    // $('[data-screensize="' + value + '"]').show();       

    // Align produkt_gruppe_div efter indlæsning
    alignFilteredProducts();    

}); 


    $.each( searchScreens, function( key, value )
    {                       
    $('.produkt_gruppe_div').each(function( index, element ) 
    {               
    if( $( this ).is( ':visible' ) )
    {
    // Vis kun de valgte screensizes på siden
    //$( '[data-screensize="' + value + '"]' ).show();
    $( '.produkt_gruppe_div' ).not('[data-screensize="' + value + '"]').fadeOut( 300 );
 }
    alignFilteredProducts();
    });
});                 

} 
else 
{
$('.produkt_gruppe_div').show();
}   
}
```

The best, Klemme

Comment: Share sample html code

Comment: can you provide a sample markup

Comment: if possible create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i recently did this in my project for the product filtering... and its very big jquery code...

Answer (score 1):

*Develop your code by this example*

For example

Your `div` is looks like

```
<div class="products" data-brand="acer" data-price="2995" data-screensize="15.6" data-processor="intel">
   Product Details
</div>
<div class="products" data-brand="acer" data-price="3000" data-screensize="13" data-processor="intel">
   Product Details
</div>
```

You can filter that `div`s by

first you have to hide all the `products` div

```
$("div.produts").hide();
```

And then show the particular div by attribute

ex :

```
$('div.produts[data-brand="acer"][data-screensize="13"]').show();
```

reference: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Answer (score 0):

## Final [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6L8X/)

**Updates:** you select one screen, you will available brands turns RED, if you click any brands with RED, you should see the filters workings. NOW if you click any other options then RED, you will see more products added inside GRID. i hope this is what you wanted..

I have created a fiddle for DEMO purpose: http://jsfiddle.net/xZLrf/

hope this is useful to understand the logic..

## HTML: (this is just a sample to understand the logic)

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="acer" value="acer" class="cb" />Acer</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="dell" value="dell" class="cb" />Dell</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="hp" value="hp" class="cb" />HP</label>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="product available filter-enable" data-name="acer">acer</div>
    <div class="product available filter-enable" data-name="acer">acer</div>
    <div class="product available filter-enable" data-name="acer">acer</div>
    <div class="product available filter-enable" data-name="acer">acer</div>
    <div class="product available filter-enable" data-name="dell">dell</div>
    <div class="product available filter-enable" data-name="dell">dell</div>
    <div class="product available filter-enable" data-name="dell">dell</div>
    <div class="product available filter-enable" data-name="dell">dell</div>
    <div class="product available filter-enable" data-name="dell">dell</div>
    <div class="product available filter-enable" data-name="hp">hp</div>
    <div class="product available filter-enable" data-name="hp">hp</div>
    <div class="product available filter-enable" data-name="hp">hp</div>
    <div class="product available filter-enable" data-name="hp">hp</div>
    <div class="product available filter-enable" data-name="hp">hp</div>
</div>
```

## Jquery:

```
$(document).on("change", ".cb", function () {
    var selectedCBValue = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        ShowAvailableProducts(selectedCBValue);
    } else {
        ShowAllProducts();
    }
});

function ShowAvailableProducts(selectedName) {
    $('.product').each(function (k, div) {
        var divValue = $(div).data("name");
        if (divValue == selectedName) {
            $(div).show();
        } else {
            $(div).hide();
        }
    });
}

function ShowAllProducts() {
    $('.product').show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Patel! It doesnt seem to work the way im after unfortunately. If you check all, you only get the last checed in the output.

Comment: yes i know.. if you want to select multiple options then it fails.. this was just a sample... i have recently created this for my project and its very difficult. so give me some time and will work on your fiddle.#

Comment: Appreciate it! Seems you are thinking the same as I am regarding this filtering function. Optimal would be to make it dynamic, so more filtereing options can be put on. I have cleaned a bit up in the jsfiddle, in the Javascript. Hope it helps to see what im after!

Comment: You might need to check if the JQuery library is correctly attached in the fiddle. Should be though :-)

Comment: Very nice Patel! I was looking to get to display multiple brands, at the same time with a certain filter of screensize = 15.4, just an example. Ill post an answer here with code that lets me select multiple brands, and then narrow them down to say 15.4". Then my problem is that i can only choose one screensize with my current code, and then i loose all products from the screen. It might be possible to integrate in you functions, you reckon?

Comment: filtering is a very probalmatic situation where you cans select multiple checkbox from screens and brands and display results. BUT thats a very long code fro me to write in jsfiddle. you try your best and will see if i can update the fiddle when i get time..

Comment: @Klemme: please see my final fiddle file and let me know... also read the update description in my answer.. please accept my answer if you are happy.